# Tannery's Convergence Theorem

Tags: analysis

This appears as the 7th exercise of Chapter 10 in Apostol's book of *Mathematical Analysis*. $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions and $p_n$ is an increasing sequence such that $p_n \rightarrow +\infty$. We have that

1. The sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a, b]$ for every $b \ge a$.
2. Each $f_n$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a, b]$ for every $b \ge a$.
3. $|f_n(x)| < g(x)$ almost everywhere on $[a, +\infty)$ for some nonegative g, which is improper Riemann integratable on $[a, +\infty)$.

Prove that $f$ and $|f|$ are improper Riemann-integrable on $[a, +\infty)$, the sequence $\{\int_a^{p_n}f_n(x)dx\}$ converges and
$$
\int_a^{+\infty}f(x)dx = \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\int_a^{p_n}f_n(x)dx.
$$
It is easy to verify that the improper Riemann integral exists, but the convergence of $\{\int_a^{p_n}f_n(x)dx\}$ is frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$, since $f,g$ are improper Riemann integrable, choose some $b_{0}>a$ large enough such that $\left|\displaystyle\int_{b}^{\infty}f(x)dx\right|<\epsilon$ and $\displaystyle\int_{b}^{\infty}g(x)dx<\epsilon$ for all $b\geq b_{0}$. Now uniform convergence of $(f_{n})$ on $[a,b_{0}]$ gives some $N$, 
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{a}^{b_{0}}f_{n}(x)dx-\int_{a}^{b_{0}}f(x)dx\right|<\epsilon,~~~~n\geq N.
\end{align*}
We may assume also that $p_{n}>b_{0}$ for all such $n$, then
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{a}^{p_{n}}f_{n}(x)dx-\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx\right|&\leq\left|\int_{a}^{b_{0}}f_{n}(x)dx-\int_{a}^{b_{0}}f(x)dx\right|\\
&~~~~+\left|\int_{b_{0}}^{p_{n}}f_{n}(x)dx-\int_{b_{0}}^{\infty}f(x)dx\right|\\
&<\epsilon+\int_{b_{0}}^{p_{n}}|f_{n}(x)|dx+\left|\int_{b_{0}}^{\infty}f(x)dx\right|\\
&<2\epsilon+\int_{b_{0}}^{p_{n}}g(x)dx\\
&<2\epsilon+\int_{b_{0}}^{\infty}g(x)dx\\
&<3\epsilon.
\end{align*}